# Taking values of select boxes and running through array to determine percentage

Tags: arrays

Hello I have a project on hand where I have to calculate how long a mom can expect her babies colic to last. They do this by selecting the age their babies colic started in weeks as well as how old their baby is currently. I then subtract their current age by the age their colic started and take that number and run it through an array that has assigned values for the left over number to get an overall percentage.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="colicStartForm" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">

               <fieldset>
                <h1>Colic Duration Calculator</h1>
<p>In 1954, Pediatrician Morris Wessel published a study on the behavior of infants with symptoms of inconsorable crying and developed the modern definition of colic known as the rule of threes (link to rule of three on colic page). His guidelines have been used ever since by Peditraicians  to diagnose infant colic. Our tool below uses a statistical model derived from Wessles original clinical data to help you assess the how long your baby's colic will last. Please note this information is for educational and information purposes only and is not a substitute the advice of a qualified physician (link to disclaimer).</p>
<h2>When Will My Child's Colic End?</h2>
<p>At what age did your child begin crying inconsolably? </p>
                <label >Weeks</label>

                <select id="weeks" name='weeks' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="0">Select Week</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
                <option value="32">32</option>
                <option value="33">33</option>
                <option value="34">34</option>
                <option value="35">35</option>
               </select>
                <br/>

                <p>How old is your child now? </p>
                <label >Weeks</label>

                <select id="weeks2" name='weeks2' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="0">Select Week</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
                <option value="32">32</option>
                <option value="33">33</option>
                <option value="34">34</option>
                <option value="35">35</option>
               </select>
                <br/>

                <p>__________________</p>

                <div id="totalPrice"></div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>
</div>  
       </form>
    </div><!--End of wrap-->

</body>
```

Script

```
// Set up of Wessel data array
// The keys represent what percent of babies colic will end by that week
// The values represent the week
var wessel_data = new Array();
wessel_data[1]="1.196%";
wessel_data[2]="4.850%";
wessel_data[3]="12.288%";
wessel_data[4]="23.649%";
wessel_data[5]="37.528%";
wessel_data[6]="51.661%";
wessel_data[7]="64.002%";
wessel_data[8]="73.444%";
wessel_data[9]="79.891%";
wessel_data[10]="83.905%";
wessel_data[11]="86.263%";
wessel_data[12]="87.670%";
wessel_data[13]="88.635%";
wessel_data[14]="89.470%";
wessel_data[15]="90.336%";
wessel_data[16]="91.296%";
wessel_data[17]="92.347%";
wessel_data[18]="93.453%";
wessel_data[19]="94.561%";
wessel_data[20]="95.618%";
wessel_data[21]="96.579%";
wessel_data[22]="97.413%";
wessel_data[23]="98.106%";
wessel_data[24]="98.656%";
wessel_data[25]="99.077%";
wessel_data[26]="99.386%";
wessel_data[27]="99.604%";
wessel_data[28]="99.753%";
wessel_data[29]="99.851%";
wessel_data[30]="99.914%";
wessel_data[31]="99.952%";
wessel_data[32]="99.975%";
wessel_data[33]="99.988%";
wessel_data[34]="99.996%";
wessel_data[35]="100%";

var week = []; //set week to new empty array
for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) //loop from 0 to 34 by increments of 1
{
    week.push(i); //push (add) the element of the loops to week (an array)
}

function getWeeksStarted()
{
    var weekStarted=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="colicStartForm"
    var theForm = document.forms["colicStartForm"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="weeks"
     var selectedWeek = theForm.elements["weeks"];

    //set week equal to value user chose
    //For example week["1".value] would be equal to 1
    weekStarted = week[selectedWeek.value];

    //finally we return week
    return weekStarted;
}

function getCurrentWeek()
{
    var weekStarted=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="colicStartForm"
    var theForm = document.forms["colicStartForm"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="weeks2"
     var selectedWeek = theForm.elements["weeks2"];

    //set week equal to value user chose
    //For example week["1".value] would be equal to 1
    weekStarted = week[selectedWeek.value];

    //finally we return week
    return weekStarted;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total weeks by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we subtract the values they return together
    var colicWeeks = getCurrentWeek() - getWeeksStarted();


var percentage = wessel_data[colicWeeks]; //since this will be an integer you can use it to index the array.

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Your child has currently had colic for "+ colicWeeks + " weeks. The odds of your childs colic resolving in this timeframe is " + percentage;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

I have the subtraction working so that I get the left over number from subtracting their current age minus the age their colic started. What I dont have working is taking that number and running it through the wessel_data array to get the percentage.

```
Updated
Now that the subtraction and the percentage are working I was wondering how to make it so the selections subtraction and percentage dont show until after the second select box is selected. Then I can show the results. I also want to take the result and show them set percentages of weeks based on which week is a set value of 80%, 95% and 99% so they will have some sort of idea of how much longer they have.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

For the show hide divobj would it be best to put it into an if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to use the number of weeks to determine the percentage, you should reverse the way you are indexing into your `wessel_data`.  Right now, you would need the percentage to find the age, but if you reversed that like

```
wessel_data[1]= "1.196%";
wessel_data[2]= "4.850%"; //etc.
```

Or Using a static array assignment:

```
wessel_data = ["0%", //javascript array are 0-indexed
               "1.196%",
               "4.850%" //more elements comma-separated
              ];
```

Then your `calculateTotal()` might look something like:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var colicWeeks = getCurrentWeek() - getWeeksStarted(); 
    var percentage = wessel_data[colicWeeks]; //since this will be an integer you can use it to index the array.

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "The probability that your childs colic will end in "
        + colicWeeks + " weeks is " + percentage + "%";

}
```

On an unrelated note, your previous syntax of `wessel_data["1.196%"]=1;` is actually adding a property to the array object, instead of placing the data into the array itself.

A quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s86wv3ck/1/).

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I rearranged the the wessel_data array to account for the age not percentage, but how to I assign the leftover number of colicWeeks and associate it with the wessel_data array. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `function getWesselPercentage() {

        var percentage=0;
        // Take colicWeeks and run it through wessel array to get percentage

        var wesselPercentage = colicWeeks();

        percentage = wessel_data[wesselPercentage.value];

        return percentage;
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan Yuyu. I created a fiddle of it here but for some reason its not working although it works great in the browser. [link] http://jsfiddle.net/jessemfulton/ec3L12zh/4/ I need to customize a few more things such as having it only display the results after the second selection is selected as well as show the probability of 4 options I will compare against such as their is a 50% probability the colic will end in 6 weeks, 80% probability it will end in 9 weeks, etc.

Comment: @jfulton it would be a lot better if you put this extra info into the question itself.  The fiddle you provided is nice for anyone else who want to try to help.  Don't be afraid to edit your question to make it better and easier to understand or answer.  And list _all_ specifications there too.  I've forked your fiddle with a quick fix in my answer, but that's all I have time for.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am new at this whole process and dont know the exact way to do this but with your help I am learning.